# How to align Top/Left/Bottom/Right of selected objects (FabricJS)

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

```js
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    
    var red = new fabric.Rect({
      top: 100,
      left: 0,
      width: 80,
      height: 50,
      fill: 'red'
    });
    var blue = new fabric.Rect({
      top: 0,
      left: 100,
      width: 50,
      height: 70,
      fill: 'blue'
    });
    var green = new fabric.Rect({
      top: 100,
      left: 100,
      width: 60,
      height: 60,
      fill: 'green'
    });
    
    canvas.add(red, blue, green);
    
    const alignLeft = document.getElementById('align_left');
    
    alignLeft.onclick = function() {
      const objs = canvas.getActiveObjects();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" ></canvas>
  <button id="align_left">Align Left</button>
```

Looking for a utility method to align edges (top,right,bottom,left) of array of objects from canvas.getActiveObjects in FabricJS v3

http://jsfiddle.net/rlightner/bzs0798x/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [object alignment in fabric js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47408816/object-alignment-in-fabric-js)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#align_left').click(function(){canvas.getActiveObject().set({left:0);})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of your code and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.